# I want to create a CGSize variable using LLDB. The CGSizeMake method has been wrong

Tags: xcode, lldb

```
e CGSize $s = (CGSize)CGSizeMake(10, 10)
error: call to 'CGSizeMake' is ambiguous
candidate function
candidate function
candidate function
```

How to write is right, ask for help

现在重启了Xcode后出现了这个问题

```
(lldb) CGSize $s = (CGSize)CGSizeMake(10, 10)
error: 'CGSize' is not a valid command.
(lldb) e CGSize $s = (CGSize)CGSizeMake(10, 10)
(lldb) po $s
(width = 592817158.70272899, height = 592817158)
(lldb) po $s.width
592817158.70272899
(lldb)
```

This is really very strange

Comment: Not a real solution, but as a (quite ugly) workaround you could use something like `e CGSize $s; $s.width = 10; $s.height = 10` (assuming an objc rutime)

Comment: What version of lldb/Xcode are you using.  This looks like the symptom of a bug that we've mostly managed to eliminate in the most recent lldb releases. If you are still seeing this in Xcode 11, and can make available a project that shows it, please do file a bug.  I can't reproduce this failure on Xcode11.

Comment: Hello, my version is Version 11.0 (11A420a), I have consulted countless articles and materials and have not found the correct method, and I especially want to achieve this, I am using Objective-C, please help me, crazy

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in a simple app, so I can't be of very much help.  If you have a project that shows the issue and can make it available to the llvm community, please file a bug with either http://bugreporter.apple.com or http://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: Sometimes in these cases it can help to run the lldb command `expr @import CoreGraphics`.  That will instruct lldb to build the CoreGraphics "module" and import it into lldb's expression evaluation context.  You shouldn't need the cast then, so things might go a little better.

Comment: Hello, can you succeed with swift, the code in the comments downstairs, I also failed，expression var $size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
error: unknown type name 'var'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'

Comment: I deleted the.lldbinit file again, and then I restarted Xcode, which is fine now, but sometimes it goes wrong, which is a big headache

Answer (score 0):

For swift, this works for me:

```
(lldb) expression var $size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
(lldb) po $size
▿ (10.0, 10.0)
  - width : 10.0
  - height : 10.0
```

Comment: hello，How to write Objective-C？

Comment: expression var $size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
error: unknown type name 'var'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'        This has an error

Comment: Boss, have you succeeded in objective-c? Please use the following code. If you have succeeded in this one, I decide to try downloading it again

E CGSize size = (CGSize) CGSizeMake (100100).
Error: call to 'CGSizeMake' is ambiguous
Candidate function
Candidate function

Comment: it doesn't work, but solution from @Alladinian's comment worked for me `e CGSize $s; $s.width = 10; $s.height = 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the struct literal syntax: {10, 10}

e.g.

-[UITextView sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size]

(lldb) po [textView sizeThatFits:{292, 1000}]

output is (width = 270, height = 80)